# Why I see correctly my layout on my phone but on Android Studio I see it wrong?

Tags: android, android-studio, layout, screen

I have a Table Layout with six buttons. I try two configurations:

First configuration: I see all the buttons with the same distance between screen borders on Android Studio, but in my mobile phone I see that all the buttons go to the left border and all the distance between the buttons and the screen was on the right screen border.

Second configuration: I use paddingLeft on the TableLayout properties and now I see the distance is near to be the same, but not at all. On Android Studio I see it wrong, the left distance is much bigger.

I put my code and a screen captures:

Code of layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.prodintec.am_motion.QuizActivity">

<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="368dp"
    android:layout_height="495dp"
    android:paddingTop="20dp"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent">

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/HeaderTextView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="FOUR OPTIONS QUESTION" />

    </TableRow>
    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/answer1"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:paddingRight="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
            android:background="@color/primary"
            android:textColor="@color/accent"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:text="ANSWER 1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/answer2"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:paddingRight="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
            android:background="@color/primary"
            android:textColor="@color/accent"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:text="ANSWER 2" />
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/answer3"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:paddingRight="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
            android:background="@color/primary"
            android:textColor="@color/accent"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:text="ANSWER 3" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/answer4"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:paddingRight="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
            android:background="@color/primary"
            android:textColor="@color/accent"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:text="ANSWER 4" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:paddingTop="20dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/HeaderTextView2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TWO OPTIONS QUESTION" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/answer5"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:paddingRight="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
            android:background="@color/primary"
            android:textColor="@color/accent"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:text="ANSWER 1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/answer6"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:paddingRight="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
            android:background="@color/primary"
            android:textColor="@color/accent"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:text="ANSWER 2" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Screen capture of Android Studio:

[image]

Screen of emulator:

[image]

I think that the second configuration is wrong and I can't do it correctly with "paddingLeft="20dp", but I don't know how to put the buttons with the same distance between the borders and the buttons on the left and right borders. Can anyone help me? Thanks!

EDIT WITH NEW LAYOUT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.prodintec.am_motion.QuizActivity">

<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="368dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="20dp"
    android:paddingEnd="10dp"
    android:paddingStart="10dp">

    <TableRow
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/HeaderTextView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="FOUR OPTIONS QUESTION" />

    </TableRow>
    <TableRow
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/answer1"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:paddingRight="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
            android:background="@color/primary"
            android:textColor="@color/accent"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:text="ANSWER 1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/answer2"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:paddingRight="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
            android:background="@color/primary"
            android:textColor="@color/accent"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:text="ANSWER 2" />
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/answer3"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:paddingRight="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
            android:background="@color/primary"
            android:textColor="@color/accent"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:text="ANSWER 3" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/answer4"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:paddingRight="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
            android:background="@color/primary"
            android:textColor="@color/accent"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:text="ANSWER 4" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/HeaderTextView2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TWO OPTIONS QUESTION" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:id="@+id/tableRow5"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/answer5"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:paddingRight="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
            android:background="@color/primary"
            android:textColor="@color/accent"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:text="ANSWER 1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/answer6"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:paddingRight="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
            android:background="@color/primary"
            android:textColor="@color/accent"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:text="ANSWER 2" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="368dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:paddingEnd="20dp"
        android:paddingStart="20dp"
        android:paddingTop="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
        tools:layout_constraintBottom_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1">

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/HeaderTextView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="FOUR OPTIONS QUESTION" />

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/answer1"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                android:paddingRight="20dp"
                android:text="ANSWER 1"
                android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
                android:textSize="20dp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/answer2"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                android:paddingRight="20dp"
                android:text="ANSWER 2"
                android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
                android:textSize="20dp" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/answer3"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                android:paddingRight="20dp"
                android:text="ANSWER 3"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:textSize="20dp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/answer4"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                android:paddingRight="20dp"
                android:text="ANSWER 4"
                android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
                android:textSize="20dp" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:paddingTop="20dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/HeaderTextView2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="TWO OPTIONS QUESTION" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/answer5"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                android:paddingRight="20dp"
                android:text="ANSWER 1"
                android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
                android:textSize="20dp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/answer6"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                android:paddingRight="20dp"
                android:text="ANSWER 2"
                android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
                android:textSize="20dp" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: I try it and I see it perfect on Android Studio, but on emulator I see it wrong, the buttons are correct on left border but in righ border they are too close, not at the same distance as in left border.

Comment: In tablelrow include padding

Comment: Now I can see it better, but it still hasn't got the same distance between the buttons and the borders. Any idea?

Comment: @imrik can u get the answer

Comment: I share it on the Edit part of the question

Comment: Is the same as I post before, with your changes on each tablerow and on the table layout.

Comment: hi check the answer

Comment: it doesn't work, in emulator I see it wrong, all the distance is only in left border, not the same distance in both borders

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Now check the update screenshare what i work

Answer (score 0):

I fix it!

I put the TableLayout on a RelativeLayout and all works perfectly.